# Basic question about private IP addressing -Class B

Tags: ipv4

Below I will translate from decimal to binary just for the second octet

The theory says the IP range is:
172.16.0.0/12  with addresses ranging between **172.16.0.0-172.31.255.2555**

that translates to:
172.00001110.0.0      with mask on the next line
255.11110000.0.0

So the base address for this range is:

172.00000000.0.0      **which is 172.0.0.0 and not 172.16.0.0**

where is the mistake here ? ☺

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You didn't convert correct from decimal to binary. 172.16 = 10101100.00010000

Comment: Thanks...to early in the morning for me :-) Some times we fail to observe the most basic things